# How to quit one file and simultaneously open another file in vim?

Tags: multiple-files

I am currently editing one file and, after finishing its edit, I want 
to close the current file and at the same time (i.e., without closing Vim) open another file for editing.

How it can be achieved?

Comment: Use `:e filename` (or `:we filename` if you also want to write the previous file) ? (Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you)

Comment: I don't think that it will close previous file. It will be in buffer. `:buffers` will show you.

Comment: You're probably right. Would this help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269648/how-do-i-close-a-single-buffer-out-of-many-in-vim

Comment: Oh wait this is probably even better :) http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/close-and-unload-a-buffer-without-exiting-vim

Comment: You can simply use `:bd` to close the current buffer and `:e filename` to open a new one.

Comment: Is the file being open in a buffer important? I mean, you CAN wipe the buffer, but it will get wiped when you close vim.

Comment: @Tumbler41 Yes that is important. What if I do `:wq` , then I think edited content will persist to file and next I do `:bd`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think this can be done using a single command. You'll have to use a combination of commands:

1. As [statox suggested](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8107/how-to-quit-one-file-and-simultaneously-open-another-file-in-vim#comment13550_8107), delete [the current buffer](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abd) and open a new one:

   ```
   :bd | e filename
   ```
2. Or [rename the current file](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Afile_f) and edit it:

   ```
   :file filename | e
   ```

Use `:w | bd | e filename` or `:w | file filename | e` to save the current file and start on a new one.

You can, of course, use maps or custom commands to simplify this:

```
:command -nargs=+ WE w | bd | e <args>
```

Then do:

```
:WE new-filename
```