# VIM: bufnr("%") not matching number from :buffers for NERDTree buffers

Tags: buffers, plugin-nerdtree

I am using NERDTree to open files. If I am on a file path in vim and I hit `gf` this works fine for files. For folders, `gf` opens a new NERDTree buffer in this folder which is fine. I can then choose a file.
I am having a hard time to make this NERDTree buffer disappear again: Hitting `:bd` as suggested [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/close-and-unload-a-buffer-without-exiting-vim) does not do anything.

Recently, I found out the following:
When doing `:buffers` I can find the number of the buffer that I want to delete. Suppose the NERDTree buffer is 5, I can do then `:5bd`, and the NERDTree buffer is gone.

This works fine. However, when I try to make it easier by getting the number of the current buffer, from `:execute bufnr("%") "bd" <CR>`, it does not work.

In that context, I saw that the numbers from `:buffer` and `:echo bufnr("%")` are different for these NERDTree buffers.

Did anyone ever encounter this and/or has a solution?

Cheers and many thanks,

Tim

Comment: What is the reason you want to get rid of Nerdtree buffer? Is your objective is to make the file opened via Nerdtree the only file shown in vim screen?

Comment: Hi tivn, the reason I want to get rid of the Nerdtree buffer is that I just do not need it anymore after the operation (opening a specific file) is done. When cycling through the open buffers with :bprevious/:bnext, I usually do not need the Nerdtree buffer to be open all the time.

Comment: You're not meant to close the NERDTree buffer (or most plugin-created buffers) in that manner. Use `:NERDTreeToggle` or `:NERDTreeClose` as @tivn suggested.

Answer (score 1):

NERDTree provides two command that basically can be used to make it disappear: `:NERDTreeClose` and `:NERDTreeToggle`. Can you try them?

NERDTree buffer is unlisted -- which can be confirmed by indicator `u` when you type `:buffers!` . That means it is normally not included in `:bprevious` and `:bnext`. So just by  making its window disappear using two commands above is sufficient I guess.

Comment: Hi tivn,
many thanks for your suggestion. I tried it and ```:NERDTreeClose``` works for the first time, opening the NERDTree buffer as I described.
However, when opening again a folder with ```gf``` it opens a new NERDTree buffer which I cannot close anymore. This buffer then also prevents me from cyclig through it: I cannot use ```:bprevious/:bnext``` to cycle through it.
So what you say is sufficient for only opening one folder. Do you have an idea what to do when opening a second NERDTree buffer via ```gf```? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Timmi Sorry, what you said is quite confusing to me. Can you type `:buffers!` (note the exclamation mark) at the time you are being *prevented* and then take a screenshot of this?

Comment: Hi @tivn, many thanks for your patience. I did what you suggested and when prevented to cycle through all open buffers, I obtain:
https://timsdata.firewall-gateway.com/index.php/s/NZwSzSMNHbnXwmq
(sorry if this is not the correct way to provide the screenshot!)
```Thesis.html``` and ```myfile``` are files. ```test``` is a folder.
Do you need any other information? Many thanks in advance!